# $1\leq a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_k \leq m$ such that ${\rm{lcm}}(a_i,a_j)>m$ for $1\leq i<j \leq k$. Find $\sup\sum_{\ell=1}^k \frac {1}{a_\ell}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

$1\leq a_1 < a_2 < \cdots < a_k \leq m$
such that ${\rm lcm}(a_i,a_j)>m$ for $1\leq i<j \leq k$. Then find the value of $$\sup\sum_{\ell=1}^k \frac {1}{a_\ell}.$$
I made a rough estimate that $$\sum_{\ell=1}^k \frac {m}{a_\ell}<\sum_{\ell=1}^k \lfloor\frac{m}{a_\ell} \rfloor+k<\frac {2m-1}{2}+\frac {m+1}{2}=\frac {3m}{2}$$so we get a rough upper bound $\frac{3}{2}$

Comment: First of all, $H_m=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1k$ is an upper bound, and $H_m<1+\log(m).$

Comment: How do you get $\sum_{l}\lfloor m/a_l\rfloor<\frac{2m-1}2?$

Comment: You can get a lower bound by taking the sequence of all $a_l>m/2.$ This gives something like $\log(2)+O(1/m).$ Getting the constant right is a bit of work.

Comment: In your question, there are two parameters; $k$ and $m$. It should be clear which one we vary while taking the supremum, or do we vary both?

Comment: One can easily prove $\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{1}{a_i}<k-\frac{k(k-1)}{2m}$ but it doesn't seem to be very effective.

Comment: I certainly assumed that $m$ was the fixed value. Another way to write this is to ask for a subset $A\subseteq \{1,2,\dots,m\}$ such that for each distinct pair $a,b\in A,$ $\operatorname{lcm}(a,b)>m.$ Then find: $$\sup_A \sum_{a\in A}\frac1a.$$ But OP hasn't answered my first question about how they got $\frac32.$ @SB1729

Comment: @ThomasAndrews makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity of my question,in my question,m takes ${\forall}m\geq3$ and k is limited by $lcm(a_i,a_j)>m$,when we consider all situations,we may get a number which is independent of m and k